# Перегрузка оператора `<<`

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-операторов

Как правильно перегрузить этот шаблон?
У `string` перегрузка `<<` ошибки не даёт...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Point {
private:
    int x, y, z;
public:
    Point() {
        x = y = z = 0;
    }
    Point(int x, int y, int z) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }
    int getx() { return x; };
    int gety() { return y; };
    int getz() { return z; };
};
/*---------------------------------------------------*/
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(T value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
    void DataTypeSize() {
        cout << sizeof(value) << endl;
    }
    T function() { return value; }

private:
    T value;
};
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, Point &point) {
    os << point.getx() << "\t" << point.gety() << "\t" << point.getz() << endl;
    return os;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, MyClass<Point> &p) {
    os  << p.function().getx() << "\t" 
        << p.function().gety() << "\t"
        << p.function().getz() << endl;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
int main() {
    Point a(1, 2, 4);

    MyClass<Point> c(a);
    c.DataTypeSize();
    cout << c.function() << endl; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Ошибка !!!!


    string str = "Hello";

    MyClass<string> s(str);
    c.DataTypeSize();
    cout << s.function() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка:

> E0349 отсутствует оператор "<<", соответствующий этим
>   операндам Project1    e:\sources\L_149_ClassTemplate.cpp  54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы фактически возвращаете из `function()` rvalue; ссылку от него (временного значения) получить нельзя - так что либо вам надо сохранять полученное значение в переменной и использовать его для вывода, или коррректно работать с `const`:

```
int getx() const { return x; };
int gety() const { return y; };
int getz() const { return z; };

...

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Point &point) {
    os << point.getx() << "\t" << point.gety() << "\t" << point.getz() << endl;
    return os;
}
```

Ну, и добавьте `return os` в оператор вывода для `MyClass`.

Если вы не меняете что-то - всегда лучше объявить его как `const`. Неужели при выводе вы собираетесь менять выводимый объект?...

Comment: Спасибо ! О таком способе int getx() const { return x; }; я еще не в курсе.. когда const пишется между названием функции и сигнатурой

Comment: @Григорий: Что вы в данном случае назвали "сигнатурой"?

Comment: То, что в скобках фигурных. Описание функции.

Comment: @Григорий: Сигнатурой функции в С++ называется имя функции и список ее параметров. "То, что в скобках фигурных" не имеет отношения к сигнатуре.

Comment: AnT, спасибо. Я только начинаю изучение с++